# Running queries/jobs via SMSS - SQL service and SQL agent service accounts (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-agent, service-accounts

If a command, for example the below command, is executed from SQL Server Management Studio while I am logged in the session with a windows authentication login, I understood that the access to the path 'C:\SQL2019\BookStore.bak'is done  via the sql service account (set in the SQL Server Configuration Manager) and not via my login. However, if an INSERT statement is done, is it done via my login in that case?

```
BACKUP DATABASE [BookStore] TO  DISK = N'C:\SQL2019\BookStore.bak' 
WITH  COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'BookStore-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Also, I have an agent job set and in the job history it states "Executed as user: sqlagent1" which is the  sql agent service account that I have set in the SQL Server Configuration Manager. The run as in the job step properties has been left empty. However, there is no login created for this account under the Logins in SQL Server. From where does this account get permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to differentiate between doing something inside SQL Server (like the INSERT you mention) and have SQL Server or Agent do something in the OS.

**Doing something inside SQL Server (INSERT, for example):**
You login using some login (CREATE LOGIN), and then this login has a user created in the database (CREATE USER). The privileges are based on that user, with the usual things such as role membership etc. This is a big topic, but I have a feeling that you are actually after the next section. Just want to make sure we differentiate the two.

**Have SQL Server or Agent do something at the OS level:** Now you want to differentiate between SQL Server and Agent.

An example when SQL Server does anything at the OS level is BACKUP. This is always done using the SQL Server service account. (Two exceptions are xp_cmdshell where a server-wide proxy is used and bulk loading of data in some cases when an impersonation of the end-users windows account can be used.)

Then you have when Agent does something at the OS level. Yes, we're talking about all job-steps except T-SQL. For a sysadmin, by default the Agent's service account is user. For non-sysadmin, you have created and Agent Proxy to be used (basically point to a windows account and allow the job owner to use this). A sysadmin *can* also use an Agent Proxy if desired.

Finally you have when Agent does something inside SQL Server. T-SQL job-steps, in other words.

- For sysadmin, Agent does it as "itself" using the Agent login, which
  is a Windows authentication. This login is btw always a sysadmin.
- For other job owner (non-sysadmins), then agent will automatically
  use EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'job_owner_name' WITH NO REVERT. I.e., the
  stuff is done as the job owner's login context without we having to
  do anything.

Here are a couple of (old) blog posts I've written on this topic: http://sqlblog.karaszi.com/sql-server-agent-jobs-and-user-contexts/ and http://sqlblog.karaszi.com/xp_cmdshell-and-permissions/.

Comment: So for T-SQL job steps, if the owner of a job is a member of the sysadmin role, I need to grant the permissions (e.g. INSERT into a table) required by the job step to the agent's service account. If the agent's service account does not have the necessary permissions, it will still NOT use the sysadmin privileges of the job owner, right?

Comment: Also, I did not understand the part of "This login is btw always a sysadmin". NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT for example yes will be sysadmin, but the sql agent service account (configured in the 'log on as' in the configuration manager - which I am understanding will be will be the login used if the owner of the job is a member of the sysadmin role) will not always be a sysadmin.

Comment: The SQL Agent Service Account is always a sysadmin, so no need to ever grant it additional privileges.  And just because you set a different Service Account, the service doesn't loose the privilege of the Per-Service SID (NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT).  The privileges of the non-default service account and the Per-Service SID are cumulative.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft so even if the non-default service account does not exist as a login on the SQL Server instance, it will still have sysadmin server role privileges?

Comment: As David says, no need to grant anything for T-SQL if the job owner is sysadmin. Agent will execute as its own login, which is always sysadmin. The first thing Agent does at startup is to verify that it is sysadmin. If it isn't, it'll stop immediately. I.e., impossible to have Agent running if it isn't sysadmin. Somehow, the running service will get the combined privileges of the configured service account and the Service SID account (like NT Service\SQLServerAgent) - how that work at a more technical detail can probably be elaborated in a Win OS forum.

Comment: Run my T-SQL code in the blog post if you feel uncertain. Seeing is believing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Job ownership is an important concept in *SQL Server Agent*. SQL Server Agent sets the security context for job execution *based on the role of the user owning the job*.

By default, SQL Server Agent executes job steps under the SQL Server Agent service account irrespective of job ownership, or under the context of a proxy account. 
(about run as empty : Users who are not sysadmin have to access to the proxy account explicitly granted to their role or username)

The exception to this rule is T-SQL job steps, which execute under the security context of the job owner.

If the job owner is a member of the sysadmin role, then the job step executes in the context of the SQL Server Agent service account.

A common mistake when setting up jobs is to make "sa" the job owner – this will cause all T-SQL job steps to execute as the SQL Agent service account, which is a system administrator account. A better option is to set a non-sysadmin account as the job owner, and explicitly grant only the required database permissions to this account.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112276/sql-agent-job-run-as-drop-down-list-is-empty

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/setting-up-your-sql-server-agent-correctly/